# Не могу выровнять верску с flex-column на бутстрапе

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Столкнулся с проблемой при верстке на бутстрапе. при испоспользовании flex-column не работает justify-content-center. Спасибо заранее за ответ

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row text-white h-100 mx-5 ">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                <div class="text-center display-2">ILLIA KARAION</div>               
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column  justify-content-center align-items-end mb-2">
                <div class="mx-3">HOME</div>
                <div class="mx-3">ONLINE STORE</div>
                <div class="mx-3">HAUTE COUTURE</div>
                <div class="mx-3">ABOUT US</div>
                <div class="mx-3">CONTACT</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Работает, но по другой оси. Вам нужен align-items-center

Comment: спасибо, помогло